# Django admin request got values for both 'fields' and 'body' error when trying to save entry with CloudinaryField attribute

Tags: django, django-models, post, django-admin, cloudinary

I am working on a Django project and suddenly I have found that when user tries to save a new entry with an image there is an exception:
`request got values for both 'fields' and 'body', can only specify one`

I am using the Django Admin in conjunction with the Cloudinary library where I am using the CloudinaryField on the specific table.

In addition, I have one to many relationship between MainEntity and Picture. The Picture model holds a CloudinaryField.

When I am trying to use `traceback` to get a detailed error I am getting another error related with database:

```
An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

The problem arises when I am calling the save method manually after the overridden that I have made in Picture model:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.order:
            self.order = self.mainEntity.number_of_pictures() + 1
        try:
            super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        except BaseException:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

What I have found is that the exception happens in `request_encode_body` method that you can find in [this](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/urllib3/request.html) url.

Although, I cannot understand why this is happening and what causes this issue!

Thank you!

**What I have tried in detail**

I have tried to downgrade Cloudinary and Django dependencies to the versions that I was using from the beginning of the project.

Checked the Cloudinary credentials.

Found the documentation of the method that throws the exception and try to investigate more.

Comment: if you can get a detailed log of the exception that would be helpful, also can you share more your code on codesandbox.io or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'had the exact same problem as you.
I was using the 1.23.0 version of Cloudinary.
After upgrading it to the 1.33.0 (last current version) it works again.
Try upgrading your Cloudinary dependency.